# Using "although" and "but" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is the following sentence incorrect please?
*Although there are many good reasons to switch to plan B, but we must stick with plan A as long as it is feasible.*

That is, can't we use "although" is a clause of a sentence and "but" in its other clause?

Comment: It is not necessary to use both of them in the same sentence. Why do you want to use both at the same time?

Comment: Some person said it's impossible, but I couldn't find a reason for that. I posted the sentence here to find out it is a really impossible sentence or it can be possible in English.

Comment: I quite agree with Rathony. Why don't you simply use the following - "Although there are many good reasons to switch to plan B, in my/ our opinion, we must/ should stick with plan A as long as it is feasible."

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use both, so I reckon you would call that 'impossible'. Say "Although there are many reasons...we must..." OR "There are many reasons... but we must..."

Answer (score 1):

**Although**, you are providing a conjunction for a clause, **it is declarative, like this one**; **but**, I can use 'but' **here**, because **this clause is immediate.**

> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions

This site is helpful.

The reason your usage is incorrect, is because you are referring to the same clause using two different conjunctions. 'Although' is a subordinating conjunction, joining a (subordinate clause), and a (principal, or independent clause).

> "Although **there are many good reasons to switch to plan B**, but **we must stick with plan A as long as it is feasible.**" The correct usage of a subordinating conjunction, **in this case**, is known as (**concession**). Notice, you are conceding that, "**...there are many good reasons to switch to plan B**," 'Although' makes this subordinate to the independent clause, "...we must stick with plan A as long as it is feasible." **This clause is independent**, it can stand on its own.

The first clause directly following Although, is an 'explanatory clause' while the second clause is the 'Declarative clause'. So the proper structure for the sentence above, using 'Although', looks like this: Although + explanatory + declarative. 'Although', is looking forward to the declarative (independent). Both clauses are coordinated by although. Using 'But' here not only is unnecessary, but, it also suggests that the reader look back, to what 'Although' was referring to in a different form.

Although is referring to the clause that you are attempting to conjugate with the coordinating conjunction 'but'.

**Although**, the structure **looks like** this is the clause, the **real clause** it refers to, is this part; **but**, if you would like to use it as you do, you are free to do as you please; **nonetheless(same as but)**, you will **notice that this clause is not conditional**. **Although**, the previous clause makes **this one explanatory**, I know that **the real clause** being **referred to, by the conjunction (Although)**, is this one.